# JDK from extern drive without installing its files locally

Tags: java, installation, terminal, jar, homebrew

How to make applications use JDK without installing them both locally? Mac.

I try to have and extern drive(sim-card) for programs and apps I do not want to have installed in my computer. I've spend a few hours(30) trying to figure it out. Warning - I usually try things that I am unsure exist in the computer science world.

What I've done:

1. App

   - Find the installer and move the app to a new folder
   - Open content and try to run the program which ask for the JDK
2. JDK

   - Download the JDK and move the files to the same folder
   - Run the app above with bin/java and bin/jar and a few crazy mixtures of these commands
   - Tried to use jshell but things get messier
3. Brew in action

   - Tried to install JDK i a different folder without succeeding
   - Tried to install the App without luck
   - Tried to install Brew in the folder in the extern drive
   - Cry
4. Considering

   - Symlink App and JDK in the outside(extern drive) folder
   - Putting the App (package contents) together with the JDK files in the same folder
   - Invent a new wheel

Comment: You cannot "run" the Java Development Kit (unless by "run" you mean "install"). The JDK is a *kit*, not an application

Comment: That's right. I just feeling like running so everything is run. I'll edit that. I mean use the JDK to help the App run : )

Comment: you do not need the JDK to "help the App run". All you really need is the JRE  to run a Java app. The 'D' in JDK indicates that this is for *Developers*

Comment: The App in this case Jedit, keep asking for Java installed on the computer. If by java (.exe) you mean the files in the bin/ where the commands are yes. I've tried that.

Comment: Hello, I continue working on a solution for this. I'll post as soon as I get the chance. So far I have found an alternative solution, to add the JDK files to the applications needing it. Searching for a method to call the files' (JDK) exec.